# Postgresql right join with USING shows very slow execution

Tags: postgresql

I have a select:

```
with t1 as (select a,b,c,d from tab1 groub by a,b,c,d), <--- has ~10000 rows 
  t2 as (select a,b,c,d from tab2 group by a,b,c,d), <--- has ~20000 rows 
  t3 as (select a,b,c,d from tab3 group by a,b,c,d), <--- has ~20000 rows 
  t4 as (select a,b,c from tab4) <--- this table doesn't have "d" here, has 3000 rows

  select * from t1 
     right join t4 using (a,b,c) <--- the only acceptable option 
     left join t2 on t1.a=t2.a t1.b=t2.b t1.c=t2.c t1.d=t2.d 
     left join t3 on t1.a=t3.a t1.b=t3.b t1.c=t3.c t1.d=t3.d
```

So I have a table with t4 (with indexes on a,b,c) without 1 column for left join with other tables. If I use left join then I see nested loop for 40 sec. If I omit the whole table t4 total execution time is around 3 sec., with right join USING total time is 13 sec. I tried generating "d" column values - no good, falls into long nested loop with 40 sec execution. t4 with distinct on (a,b,c) - also no good. I also tried rewriting all "on" clauses for "using" - shows similar time.

Is there some better option or join strategy for this scenario? Maybe I am missing something?
Thanks

Comment: Use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) to get the query plan. Without it, it's hard to optimise the query. The DDL for the tables will also help, especially the indexes.

Comment: Without the explain plan there is not much to be said, except your *only acceptable option* seems to be the problem. Perhaps you should rethink that.